# Is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix necessarely similarly to another symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb K)$ symmetric.

Given $H\in GL_n(\mathbb K)$, is $H^{-1}AH$ necessarely symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
= 
\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$